# why toUpperCase not working in nextjs while adding slug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am following this link
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/headers

adding `x-slug` key .I am adding like this

```
module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:slug',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'x-slug',
            value: `${abc(':slug')}` // Matched parameters can be used in the value
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
  }
};
```

when I using this url
https://nextjs-vetexh--3000.local.webcontainer.io/dsd
"slug" --- > dsd

[image]
but when I using `toUppercase()` function it is not working why

```
function abc(a) {
  // working
 // return a;
 // not working
  return a.toUpperCase();
}
```

It is giving `SLUG` in capital .

**Expected output is "DSD"**
[image]

here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-vetexh?file=next.config.js

```
function abc(a) {
  // working
  // return a;
  // not working
  return a.toUpperCase();
}
module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:slug',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'x-slug',
            value: `${abc(':slug')}` // Matched parameters can be used in the value
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
  }
};
```

Comment: Where does the `abc` function come from? Presumably `value: ":SLUG"` breaks the link to `/:slug`, because that object is **not** being evaluated at the time the request is actually getting made.

Comment: any idea to change to uppercase ? expected ouptput is "DSD" it is giving `:SLUG`

Comment: here is my code https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-vetexh?file=next.config.js

Comment: It's possible you _can't_, given what your example shows. Unless you could plug in some middleware downstream, once the actual value is set, to uppercase that header if present. `value` in that object is a _template_, you're uppercasing that not the actual value.

Comment: I just shared my code . if possible can you please come code

Comment: You didn't share your code; you shared a link to your code. Please read [ask], where it says, "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also copy the code into the question itself**."

Comment: @HereticMonkey shared my code also

Comment: I don't see why you'd _expect_ that to work. Strip out the template string and the function call and you've obviously just got `value: ":SLUG"`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, FYI, `:path` is a valid syntax to get the value as per [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/headers#path-matching)

Comment: @PsyGik yes, I did read the linked docs, I mean I don't see why you'd expect that to upper-case the actual value.

Comment: I need to do some manipulation like `removing special character or remove - to _ (underscore)` ..uppercase is just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not possible in `next.config.js`, but there are other options with some tradeoffs.

### With `getServerSideProps`

You could add custom HTTP headers by matching the path for the request using `getServerSideProps` in `_app.js`:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

  // set HTTP header
  context.res.setHeader('x-slug', upperCase(context.params.slug))

  return {
    props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

The `context` parameter is an object containing the following keys:

- `params`: If this page uses a dynamic route, `params` contains the route parameters. If the page name is `[id].js` , then params will look like `{ id: ... }`.
- `req`: The HTTP IncomingMessage object.
- `res`: The HTTP response object.
- `query`: An object representing the query string.

But using `getServerSideProps` **would disable static optimization** as all pages will be only server-side rendered.

[More on Server-side Rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering)

### With Custom Server

Another way is to use a [**Custom Server**](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) and override the response headers.

```js
server.get('/:slug*', (req, res) => {
    res.set('x-slug', upperCase(req.params['slug']));
    handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
  });
```

**A custom server will remove important performance optimizations, like serverless functions and Automatic Static Optimization.**